# django display data saved from multicheckbox in template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make an publishing option, so i use this

```
class Article(models.Model):
    publish_options = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Now in my form, i used `forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple widget`. so i have this

```
PUBLISH_VISIBILITY = (
    ('All', 'All'),
    ('Paid-users', 'Paid-users'),
    ('Free Users', 'Free Users'),
    ('Public', 'Public'),
)

class PortalNoteForm(ModelForm):
    publish_options = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=PUBLISH_VISIBILITY)
    class Meta:
        model = Article
```

Now in my view i get the values for the checkbox like this

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PortalNoteForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        school_article = form.save(commit=False)
        school_article.publish_options = form.cleaned_data['publish_options']
        school_article.school_creator = admin
        school_article.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('going to somewhere'))
else:
    form = PortalNoteForm()
context = {'form':form, 'notes':notes}
```

Okay this works fine saving the value of the publish_option but as a list, even if you select only one checkbox its value comes as a list. Now the problem here is i cant get to stop these `publish_options` value from displaying as a list in django template. I have tried iterating over them but no way. I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

Well you already had a form, why do you still getting data from `request.POST`? Form is suppose to take `request.POST` and convert data into a more convenient way for you to use:

views.py

```
def view_func(request):
    form = PortalNoteForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        options = form.cleaned_data['public_options']
        # now you have options so use it
```

Comment: thats not the problem there. i said the data saves correctly. but due to the widget "forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple" that i used. the data is being saved as a list. but refuse to loop over and display its items in template

Comment: What I'm suggesting is just a better way for you to handle data. But for the sake of correctness, you should edit your question to show us what's in your `request.POST`, why can't you iterate the data.